# Get the sum of on item in a variable length list in MVC Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I using a knockout and ajax post to  upload documents to the server, and returning the document information which is then displayed in a table.

I used [Steven Sanderson's Example](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/) in doing this.

this works fine.

However, I want to get a sum of all the file sizes. I've tried this:

```
    self.Upload = function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var file = document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0];
            formData.append("FileUpload", file);
            var action = "Upload";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: options.url + action,
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    self.AddDoc(result);
                }
            });
        }

        self.AddDoc = function (data) {
            self.Model.CurrentStep().Files.push({ ID: data.ID, Name: data.Name, Extension: data.Extension, ContentType: data.ContentType, Size: data.Size, RawSize: data.RawSize, Content: data.Content, FilePath: data.FilePath, Folder: data.Folder });
        }

        self.TotalSize = ko.computed(function () {
            var total = 0;

            if (self.Model.CurrentStep() === 5) {
                ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Model.CurrentStep().Files(), function (item) {
                    total += item.RawSize;
                });
            }

            return total
        });

 <table id="FileList" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayName("Document Name")
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 150px;">
                        @Html.DisplayName("Document Size (MB)")
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 40px;">
                        @Html.DisplayName("View")
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 40px;">
                        @Html.DisplayName("Delete")
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'FileRowTemplate', foreach: Model.Step5.Files }"></tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Size)
                        <span data-bind="text: TotalSize" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

self.TotalSize is always 0.

Please how can I fix this?

**Solution:**

Following Chris Pratt's sugguest, I change this:

```
   if (self.Model.CurrentStep() === 5)
```

To
       if (self.Model.CurrentStep().Files)

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
if (self.Model.CurrentStep() === 5) {
    ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Model.CurrentStep().Files(), function (item) {
        total += item.RawSize;
    });
}
```

If `self.Model.CurrentStep()` is type equal to `5`, then it can never have a `Files` member, because a JavaScript number doesn't have anything to do with `Files`. In other words, either your if statement is wrong or the array your filtering over is wrong.

Perhaps you meant your if statement to be:

```
if (self.Model.CurrentStep().length === 5)
```